# MySQL query LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MySQL database that is used calculating money. I have two tables: balance and money.

In money table there is two columns: id (which is AUTO_INCREMENT and PRIMARY) and name. That table contains now:

```
1 | Card
2 | Cash
```

In balance table there is three columns: id (which is AUTO_INCREMENT and PRIMARY), balance, time and money_id. That table contains now:

```
1 | 200 | 2014-01-03 03:04:00 | 2
2 | 150 | 2014-01-03 03:08:00 | 2
3 | 400 | 2014-01-03 03:10:00 | 1
4 | 300 | 2014-01-03 03:12:00 | 1
5 | 100 | 2014-01-03 03:14:00 | 2
5 | 150 | 2014-01-03 03:16:00 | 2
```

So at this time there is 100 cash and 300 in card. I want a page showing that, like:

```
Cash 100
Card 300
```

But I have problem creating a query for this. I have a query, but it doesn't work how it should work:

```
SELECT 
    money.name, 
    balance.balance, 
    balance.time, 
    money.id, 
    balance.id 
FROM 
    money, 
    balance 
WHERE 
    money.id = balance.money_id 
ORDER BY 
    balance.time DESC
```

This will print this:

```
Cash 150
Cash 100
Card 300
Card 400
Cash 150
Cash 200
```

But I want only one value per money.name, and that what is sort by balance.time. I tried limit 1, but it print just:

```
Cash 150
```

Limit 2 doesn't also work, because it prints:

```
Cash 150
Cash 100
```

Any ideas?

And sorry for bad english, that isn't my native language. :D

Comment: I voted to close because this is too broad, by which I mean 'too basic'

Comment: Sounds like you want a group by but I'm not understanding your use case for this, why wouldn't you want to use limit?

Comment: Group by most likely. Try to reorganize the task

Comment: @DavidNguyen: because you want the latest cash value for every item in the 'money'-table, a limit won't do.

Comment: His question is a little misleading (not group by) but it's because he doesn't know SQL well.  He wants to show the latest balance/$ for each type of money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.name, b.balance
FROM money m
INNER JOIN balance b ON m.id = b.money_id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT b.money_id, MAX(b.time) AS `time` 
            FROM balance b 
            GROUP BY b.money_id
           ) AS A ON b.money_id = A.money_id AND b.time = A.time;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4978/2)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | NAME | BALANCE |
|----|------|---------|
|  1 | Card |     300 |
|  2 | Cash |     150 |
```

Comment: What is these A.x in end? MySQL says Unknown column.

If A means same as m, there is no m.time, just b.time.

Comment: @ Saharsh Shah ) AS A ON b.money_id = A.money_id AND b.time = A.time;

These A.money_id and A.time

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(*) 
FROM money a join balance b 
WHERE a.id = b.money_id 
GROUP BY a.name
```

Comment: That query doesn't show balance, so I edited the first line to this:
SELECT b.balance, a.name, COUNT(*)

But the problem it, that it doesn't get latest balance by balance time. So balance is wrong.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question as originally posed. But the question has changed considerably since then, which is unfortunate.